# confused: $q.when() or just call a function without it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I am relatively new to AngularJS and JavaScript in general. I have been trying to learn recently by creating my own project. I have noticed that there is no apparent difference in the funcioning of my app between a code like this:

```
$q.when(authenticationService.login($scope.username, $scope.password))
                    .then(function (response) {

                    }, function (error) {

                    });
```

and this:

```
authenticationService.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
                    .then(function (response) {

                    }, function (error) {

                    });
```

It seems like the $q.when is not really that necessary. I have done some reading and I think the lack of a difference might be due to the fact that my `authenticationService.login()` returns a promise. 
But is it just for that? Is the $q.when() only for making sure that whatever is inside is a promise? (so if it is, it leaves it and if it is not it wraps it in a promise) ?
What are possible other use cases?
Thanks!

Comment: Since second version has a working `then()` it indicates that .login() returns a promise making the `$q.when()` redundant

Comment: "*Is the $q.when() only for making sure that whatever is inside is a promise? (so if it is, it leaves it and if it is not it wraps it in a promise)?*" - Yes, exactly that. So when you know that the called function always returns a promise, you don't need to - and should not - use `$q.when`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) seems pretty clear about this:

> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

If the term "thenable" (which they've written "then-able") is unfamiliar, it's worth reviewing the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Comment: Reviewing the spec is a great idea. In terms of learning about Promises, I found the MDN to be a good resource to help ease into it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.